# when page reload react router navigate to first page v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i have conditional routing in my app and when i reload a page it's navigates to that navigates address i have set (' / ', my Home page) .the conditional routing is working well but i want when ,i reload the page( for example : i'm in "YourChildren" page ) ,I want to stay on this page( i mean "YourChildren ") and don't navigate to another page(after reloading browser ,it's navigates to my Home page  ). i have three userType that have different pages that i give it from my contex. this is my codes :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route, Navigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import ScrollToTop from './ScrollToTop';
const Dashboard = () => {
  const { activeMenu, themeSettings, setThemeSettings, currentColor, currentMode, UserType } = useStateContext();
  const [Company, setCompany] = useState(false)
  const [Doctor, setDoctor] = useState(false)
  const [Child, setChild] = useState(false)
  useEffect(() => {
    switch (UserType) {
      case "company":
        setCompany(true)
        break;
      case "Doctor":
        setDoctor(true)
        break;
      case "children":
        setChild(true)
        break;

      default:
        error("Type Not Recognized: " + UserType)
        break;
    }
  }, [UserType])
  
  return (
    <div className={currentMode === 'Dark' ? 'dark' : ''}>
      <BrowserRouter>
                      <ScrollToTop>

              <Routes basename="/Dashboard">

                {/*  Dashboard */}

                <Route path="" element={<Ecommerce />} />
                <Route path="/Dashboard/ecommerce" element={<Ecommerce />} />

                {/* Pages */}

                <Route path="/Dashboard/orders" element={<Orders />} />
                <Route path="/Dashboard/employees" element={<Employees />} />
                <Route path="/Dashboard/customers" element={<Customers />} />
                {/* <Route path="/Dashboard/customers" element={<CustomersFu />} /> */}

                {/* Apps */}

                <Route path="/Dashboard/kanban" element={<Kanban />} />
                <Route path="/Dashboard/editor" element={<Editor />} />
                <Route path="/Dashboard/color-picker" element={<ColorPicker />} />

                {/* Charts */}
                <Route path="/line" element={<Line />} />
                <Route path="/area" element={<Area />} />
                <Route path="/bar" element={<Bar />} />
                <Route path="/pie" element={<Pie />} />
                <Route path="/financial" element={<Financial />} />
                <Route path="/color-mapping"
                  element={<ColorMapping />} />
                <Route path="/pyramid" element={<Pyramid />} />
                <Route path="/stacked" element={<Stacked />} />
                {/*child  other Pages */}
                <Route path="/Dashboard/:id/child" element={Child ? <ChildFile /> : <Navigate replace to={"/"} />} />
                <Route path="/Dashboard/:id/Doctor" element={Child ? <UserAboutPage /> : <Navigate replace to={"/"} />} />
                <Route path="/Dashboard/:id/Advisor" element={Child ? <UserAboutPage /> : <Navigate replace to={"/"} />} />
                <Route path="/Dashboard/DoctorList" element={Child ? <DoctorList /> : <Navigate replace to={"/"} />} />
                <Route path="/Dashboard/paintList" element={Child ? <PaintList /> : <Navigate replace to={"/"} />} />
                <Route path="/Dashboard/ListOfAppointments" element={Child ? <ListOfAppointment /> : <Navigate replace to={"/"} />} />
                <Route path="/Dashboard/paintList/:id/Details" element={Child ? <PaintDetails /> : <Navigate replace to={"/"} />} />
                {/* Apps in doctor*/}
                <Route path="/Dashboard/Calendar" element={Doctor ? <IndexCalendar /> : <Navigate replace to={"/"} />} />
                {/* pages in doctor*/}
                <Route path="/Dashboard/Referees" element={Doctor ? <Referees /> : <Navigate replace to={"/"} />} />
                <Route path="/Dashboard/Credits" element={Doctor || Company ? <Credits /> : <Navigate replace to={"/"} />} />
                <Route path="/Dashboard/CompleteProfil" element={Doctor ? <CompleteProfile /> : <Navigate replace to={"/"} />} />
                <Route path="/Dashboard/CommentManager" element={Doctor || Company ? <CommentManager /> : <Navigate replace to={"/"} />} />
                <Route path="/Dashboard/VisitList" element={Doctor ? <VisitsRequest /> : <Navigate replace to={"/"} />} />
                {/* pages in company*/}
                <Route path="/Dashboard/YourChildren" element={Company ? <YourChildren /> : <Navigate replace to={"/"} />} />
                <Route path="/Dashboard/YourAdviser" element={Company ? <YourDoctors /> : <Navigate replace to={"/"} />} />
                <Route path="/Dashboard/YourChildren/:id/GetCard" element={Company ? <ChildrenCard /> : <Navigate replace to={"/"} />} />
                <Route path="/Dashboard/YourChildren/:id/Details" element={Company ? <ChildFile /> : <Navigate replace to={"/"} />} />


              </Routes>
              </ScrollToTop>

      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: Sorry, it's a bit unclear what you are trying to ask for help with. Can you try to more clearly explain what the issue is and the steps to reproduce it? What is the expected behavior versus the observed behavior?

Comment: thanks for your response i add more details and hope it's enough

Comment: So basically you have some rudimentary route protection and you want the `userType` value to keep a user on the path they were one prior to a page reload, is this correct? Can you add the `useStateContext` hook and React context provider code to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issue

The issue is that the routes make redirecting decisions based on incorrect initial state values.

```
const [Company, setCompany] = useState(false); // <-- initially false

...

<Route
  path="/Dashboard/YourChildren"
  element={Company // <-- initially false
    ? <YourChildren />
    : <Navigate replace to="/" /> // <-- render redirect
  }
/>
```

If the current path is `"/Dashboard/YourChildren"` and the page is reloaded, then on the initial render cycle when the app mounts the `Company` state value is `false` and the redirect to `"/"` is rendered. The `useEffect` hook doesn't run until *the end* of the initial render cycle to set the state to the correct value.

## Solution

Provide accurate initial state values based on the `UserType` state.

Example:

```
const { ..., UserType } = useStateContext();

const [Company, setCompany] = useState(UserType === "company");
const [Doctor, setDoctor] = useState(UserType === "Doctor");
const [Child, setChild] = useState(UserType === "children");
```

Comment: thanks man for your answer, it worked , i had guessed this is my problem but i didn't have any idea for solution thanks again.